# Are laws of reflection valid in all cases?

Tags: optics, reflection

Imagine a light ray incident on a plane mirror along a vector i+j-k. The normal on incidence point is along i+j.
In this case the incident ray, reflected ray and the normal do not lie in the same plane. How valid are laws of reflection here?
Should we apply laws of reflection by considering only the components that get reflected and thereby ignoring 'k' component?
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: where do you think the reflected rays are going? $\vec k_i \propto \hat i + \hat j - \hat k$, what does $\vec k_r$ look like?

Comment: only i and j components are reflected.k component remains unchanged.

Comment: Please provide mode details. Like "here is how I calculated the direction of reflected ray, the result is ..., and I think that the vectors (here goes coordinates of incident, normal andreflected vectors) do not lie in the same plane because ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is rotate to a new coordinates system with

$$\hat x = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[\hat i + \hat j] $$

and

$$ \hat z = \hat k $$

as "k" is a assigned to wave vectors.

The in-going wave has a wave vector (normalized);

$$ \hat k_{in} = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[\hat x - \hat z]$$

The mirror is in the x-y plane:

$$ \hat n = \hat z $$,

so the reflected wave is:

$$ \hat k_{out} = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[\hat x + \hat z]$$

Now take the scalar triple product to see the volume of the parallelepiped spanned:

$$ V = \hat n \cdot (\hat k_{in} \times \hat k_{out})$$
$$ V =  \hat z \cdot [(\hat x-\hat z) \times (\hat x + \hat z)]/2$$
$$ V = \hat z \cdot (-\hat y) = 0$$

Zero means they are coplanar.